# Issue with writing text on a particular image frame in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, html5-canvas

I am working on a project using html5 in which I have a canvas on which I am drawing 5 images one after the other with a time spacing of 1 second. I need to be able to write some text on a particular frame dynamically which I am unable to do. Say for example when I enter 3;hello in the text field, when the third frame is drawn onto the canvas, it should display the text hello on it. below is my javascript function for the same.

```
function overlayText(){

    string2 = document.getElementById("myTextArea"); 
    var splitString = (string2.value).split(";");
    var temp = splitString[0].split(",");
    var frameNumber = splitString[0];
    var text = splitString[1];
    //var array = text.split("\n"); 
alert(frameNumber); alert(text);

ctx.font = "16pt Arial";

    if(frameNumber!=0 && frameNumber<im1.length) {
        for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
            //var temp = array[i];
            ctx.textAlign="left";
            ctx.textBaseline="bottom";
            ctx.fillText(im1[frameNumber].text[i], 40, 50); //Seems to be the issue

        }
    }

    else alert("Chill out!!Try entering realistic frame number");
}
```

I guess I am unable to use the array appropriately. Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more code? This will be difficult to debug without knowing what `im1` is. The HTML would also be helpful. A fiddle would be great

Comment: @chiliNUT -  here is the fiddle link for required code for what I am trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/jhcedkhv/

Comment: `im1[frameNumber].text[i]` is not valid text --- im1[frameNumber] is an array element containing an image url and text[i] is a letter inside the "text" string. So if you desire output like "images/3.png Hello" you need to (1) correctly parse the text from myTextArea, and (2) `fillText( im1[framenumber]+' '+correctlyParsedText, 40,50);`

Comment: Hi.. I have been busy with something else but this problem still persists.. can someone please help me.. here is the fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/dnLrt9w7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can not draw text under already drawn image. You have to store all texts in some shared variable(array similar to images' URLs i.e.) and draw text right after corresponding `drawImage` call inside `setInterval` handler. Unfortunately your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: So you are saying either text of another image cannot be drawn on an existing image dynamically? I have done the static image (such as the URL that you mentioned here) and that works fine, but I need it dynamcally. Is there a possibility that I could use another canvas of same size over this canvas to write text or draw images?

Comment: No, you can draw text over image. Actually I do not see where `overlayText` is even called in your fiddle. If you never call the function, it definitely won't work.

Comment: If you look into the HTML in the fiddle, the div tag has the OvelayText function called. This is the line in the code:  <button onclick="overlayText()">Display Live Text</button>  Could you please help I go forward from here? Here is the link again for reference. http://jsfiddle.net/jhcedkhv/

Comment: Then your text will be drawn only when you click button. But then `setInterval` handler will work and it will draw new image over text. You need to call `overlayText` inside the handler.

Comment: @Freywar- It looks like the issue is in this line of code: ctx.fillText(im1[frameNumber].text[i], 40, 50);  Could you please let me know if there is an issue in how I am using the array? Is this a wrong notation? Also, in regards with your previous comment, my intention is to draw the text only on that particular frame. The next frame should erase the text. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `im1` is array of strings, `im1[frameNumber]` is plain string, not an object, but you try to get some property `text` from it. You should store texts in separate array